# Find Datediff in the same column

Tags: sql

I have a BorderCrossingData Table. A would like to get the PassportNames have minimum one BorderCrossingDateTime-interval what is longer than 4 month.

```
BorderCrossingID    PassportNumber  BorderCrossingDateTime
1                    ER-2222        2019-01-07 22:11:12.000
2                    ER-2222        2019-01-07 23:11:12.000
3                    KL-5233        2018-10-03 17:10:39.000
130                  FF-4444        2019-01-08 11:11:11.000
5                    ER-1111        NULL
6                    KL-5686        NULL
7                    ER-1111        NULL
8                    KL-5235        NULL
9                    QW-5656        NULL
10                   DF-5685        NULL
11                   KL-4558        NULL
--------
113                 LL-8989         2019-01-15 16:24:26.333
114                 ZZ-0005         2019-01-17 16:18:12.273
115                 LL-0223         2019-01-17 16:19:12.000
116                 ER-2222         2019-01-03 08:24:29.000
117                 ER-2222         2019-02-01 08:25:03.873
118                 ER-2222         2019-03-13 08:25:17.000
119                 ER-2222         2019-04-10 08:25:32.000
120                 ER-2222         2019-09-30 08:25:47.000
```

I have already get BorderCrossings have BorderCrossingDateTime and put them in Order.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PassportNumber, BorderCrossingDateTime FROM Passports
WHERE DATEDIFF(Compare 2 upcoming DateTimes)
EXCEPT
SELECT PassportNumber, BorderCrossingDateTime FROM Passports
WHERE BorderCrossingDateTime IS NULL 
ORDER BY BorderCrossingDateTime
```

The result should be like this:

```
PassportName
ER-2222
TO-0140
NN-4444
TP-0140
TT-0140
WU-5645
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please specify which DBMS you are using (SQL Server, MySQL etc.) in your tags :)

Comment: @Brokkoli . . . How do you know which direction they are going in?  Are you looking for people spending 4 months on just one side of the border?

Comment: It was in the task I got. I had to make 7 queries, and the last one was the one above. Anyway in the program the number is a parameter so it is changeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will work. I have tested in SQL Server. I am using [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql), [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) functions to find out the previous, next border crossing dates.

```
    CREATE TABLE #borderCrossing (BorderCrossingID INT, PassportNumber VARCHAR(10), BorderCrossingDateTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #borderCrossing
VALUES (1, 'ER-2222', '2019-01-07 22:11:12.000'), (2, 'ER-2222', '2019-03-07 22:11:12.000'), (3, 'ER-2222', '2019-08-07 22:11:12.000');

SELECT DISTINCT PassportNumber
FROM (
    SELECT BorderCrossingId, BorderCrossingDateTime AS CurrentBorderCrossingDateTime, passportNumber, lag(BorderCrossingDateTime, 1, NULL) OVER (
            PARTITION BY passportNumber ORDER BY BorderCrossingDateTime
            ) AS prevBorderCrossingDateTime, lead(BorderCrossingDateTime, 1, NULL) OVER (
            PARTITION BY passportNumber ORDER BY BorderCrossingDateTime
            ) AS nextBorderCrossingDateTime
    FROM #borderCrossing
    ) AS t
WHERE DATEDIFF(mm, prevBorderCrossingDateTime, nextBorderCrossingDateTime) > 4
```

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful! I changed the LEAD part to the "Basic" BorderCrossingDateTime to have PassportName if it has only two DateTime. Thanks again!